# 'vagrant up' not working while installing homestead on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I run ubuntu 14.04 trusty. I installed virtual box and vagrant in order to be able to use laravel. I installed laravel homestead via git and I am trying to run the command 'vagrant up' but I get an error. Please what am I doing wrong?

I tried to add vagrant box with this command 'vagrant box add laravel/homestead' but I got the error below:

```
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104
```

Comment: try with full link `vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead`

Comment: If you receive SSL read error  first time, try adding again in same way "vagrant box add laravel/homestead", this will add it quickly from temp directory and hopefully without error (this worked for me at least).

Answer (score 7):

Can you run `vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead --insecure`

Using the `--insecure` flag it does not validate SSL certificates so you should not have the SSL error

You may need to clean `~/.vagrant.d/tmp/` folder if you have some uncompleted transfer

You can also download the ssl certificate and directly use it to bypass the error

```
$ vagrant box add --cacert <certificate> box_name
```

Comment: This is more of a workaround. The last time I updated too I faced this and had to re-downloaded adding --insecure and the same thing happened now. Any permanent fixes?

Comment: you could still add the certificate from the https URL so it will always be verified

Comment: how to add the certificate so that it will always be verified?

Comment: @ApitJohnIsmail you can run `vagrant box add --cacert <certificate> box_name`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error yesterday twice. I just removed the tmp folder in ~/.vagrant.d and ran again 'vagrant box add laravel/homestead'. I realized that when my laptop suspends due to non-activity, the command just fails, so what I did is disable the suspend after 30 min and activate 'Never Suspend' (that option depends obviously on your environment)

On Ubuntu 14 just right click the battery icon and choose Energy Options.